# Quartz.net JobStoreTX Job Save issue

Tags: c#, .net, jobs, quartz.net

I'm trying to run Quartz.net server for my website maintance tasks.
I create Jobs and triggers in my WCF application (hosted on IIS). So they can be stored in database (SQL Server).

Now i can't understand ADO.NET Job Store. 
Here is my web.config part for Quartz.net:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
</configSections>
<quartz>
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
        <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
        <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />
        <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
        <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
        <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.**SqlServerDelegate**, Quartz" />
        <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
        <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="ConnectionString" />
        <add key="quartz.dataSource.ConnectionString.connectionString" value="Server=*;Database=*;Uid=*;Pwd=*" />
        <add key="quartz.dataSource.ConnectionString.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
        <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="PaymentService" />

        <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true" />
</quartz>
```

And here is my global.asax:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static ISchedulerFactory Factory;
        public static IScheduler Scheduler;

        protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            Scheduler = Factory.GetScheduler();

            JobKey JobKey = new JobKey("GetOrderInfoJob", "Project");
            if (Scheduler.CheckExists(JobKey))
                Scheduler.DeleteJob(JobKey);

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<PaymentServiceLogic>()
                .WithIdentity(JobKey)
                .StoreDurably()
                .RequestRecovery()
                .Build();

            TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey("GetOrderInfoTrigger", "Project");

            TriggerBuilder tb = TriggerBuilder.Create();
            tb.WithIdentity(triggerKey );
            tb.WithSimpleSchedule(a => a.WithIntervalInMinutes(1));
            tb.StartNow();
            tb.ForJob(job);
            ITrigger trigger = tb.Build();
            Scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger);

            Scheduler.Start();
        }
}
```

Once i've started WCF service on localhost, QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS table in SQL Server for jobs had 1 entry, but no triggers.
I've tested this code a couple times and now no jobs are storing and therefore i have this exception:
*Couldn't store trigger job: The job referenced by the trigger does not exist.*

Is there some bug with job's building or AdoJobStore?

And the second question is about how to do correct shutdown in global.asax. Now i've decided this method:

```
protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ICollection<IScheduler> all = Factory.AllSchedulers;
            foreach (IScheduler item in all)
            {
                item.Shutdown(true);
            }
        }
```

and implementing my own logging in Application_Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, sure whether it is a good idea to ask two questions in one, but the answer to your first question is you need to change

```
Scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger);
```

to

```
Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

The former is when the job has previously been added to the scheduler, whereas the latter adds both the job and trigger at the same time.